# How do I put all my Illustrator and Photoshop toolbars and windows in one single window?

Tags: adobe-creative-suite, osx

I have all my Illustrator and Photoshop toolbars scattered throughout my desktop, and I simply want all of my menus, toolbars, and files to be within one window.

This is often super annoying because the toolbars don't pop up when my files are open depending on what desktop I am on.

Answer (score 9):

Going to the "Window" menu, and checking "Application Frame" will condense all toolbars and files into one window in Illustrator and Photoshop (using CS6).

Comment: +1 Nice tip! Never knew about that before, I thought it was just something we had to endure while working on a Mac.

Comment: Sometimes you might need to go into Windows > Workspaces > Reset ## in order for you panel groups sick inside the application frame ;)

Answer (score 0):

Window > Arrange > Consolidate all windows. That way you don't have to use the Application Frame if you prefer the Application bar.

Comment: Sorry—I'm thinking of InDesign. It's "Consolidate All to tabs" as the final item in that path in Photoshop.

Comment: Please edit your own answer (you should be allowed to do that) and if possible, can you add a screenshot?  Welcome to GD.SE!